# Can I force a colspan header cell to sort either of its columns?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

Say I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th colspan="2">Full Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>Rasmus</td>
            <td>Lerdorf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The first and last names are in two separate cells for formatting and readability reasons. By default, datatables ignores the colspan'd *Full Name* header cell, and won't make it toggle the sorting.

Is there a way to force datatables to explicitly make either of the columns in the table body sortable? For example, I want to sort by the last name only.

I searched, but only found several year old hacks and workarounds (e.g. creating empty columns etc.)

Answer (score 0):

DataTables support `rowspan` and `colspan` in table header but only if there is one `th` cell for each column.

For example

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
           <th colspan="2">Full Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>Rasmus</td>
            <td>Lerdorf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```